# Search tags and return location using python-instagram

Tags: python, geolocation, instagram-api

I am trying to use python-instagram to perform a tag search and return location.

I am recieving the error:
**AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'location'**

Here is what I have tried:

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI

client_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
access_token="xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

api = InstagramAPI(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret,access_token=access_token)
tag = 'wtcampus'
search= api.tag_recent_media(tag_name=tag)

if ['location'] is not None:
    for media in search:
        print media.location.point.latitude
        print media.location.point.longitude
```

Im confident I am a parsing some location object after performing the following tests...

```
count = 0 

if ['location'] is not None:
    for media in search:
        count = count + 1
print count
```

Which returns 2. How do I return the lat and long of these objects?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ['location'] is not None:
    for media in search:
        print media.location.point.latitude
        print media.location.point.longitude
```

This `if` statement will always execute. I haven't worked with the Instagram API, but believe this should work:

```
if search['location']:
    for media in search:
        print media.location.point.latitude
        print media.location.point.longitude
```

For the future, `if x is not None` can be simply written as `if not x`.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Lukasz Salitra. Same error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'location. :/

Comment: @remmi11 What's the output of `search`? Just print it and see what's in it.

Comment: `if ['location'] is not None: print search` returns ([ ], None)

Comment: Print search immediately after assigning it. 
`search= api.tag_recent_media(tag_name=tag)`, then newline and 
`print search`